# mocking function with same name and different argument using proxyquire

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, proxyquire

I have a file with format below which uses certain module.

```
let module = require('modulename')
let r = module()
r.post(variable, callbackFunction)
r.post(variable, variable, variable, callbackFunction)
```

I am trying to mock this two function using proxyquire as given below

```
let module= function(){
    return {
        post: (variable, callback) => {
            //some codes
            return callback(error, res)},
        post: (variable,variable,variable, callback) => {
            //somecode
            return callback(error, res)}
    }}
let mock = proxyquire(filepath,{'modulename':module})
```

Since it contain two function with same name, i am unable to mock these two post function as the function call goes to only one function(second function). How to resolve this? Anyody got any idea? I am fairly new to unit testing and proxyquire

Comment: So you want to mock the `r.post` method returns different value based on parameters, right?